# ANT Script to move specified File

Tags: ant, salesforce

I'm trying to write a simple ANT script that copies a file/folder to a specified directory. For example by running:

```
ant deploy src/classes/myClass.class
```

The file "myClass.class" is copied from "src/classes/" to "deploy/src/classes/". Also, this should work for a specified folder so running:

```
ant deploy src/classes/
```

Should copy all files from src/classes" to "deploy/src/classes". Also, the destination folders will not exist before the script is ran and would therefore need "touching" first...

From looking around copying the files isn't really an issue but I can't figure out how to get this to work with parameters (as above)...

Does anyone know how this can be actived?

Answer (score 1):

Ant is not a computer language. It's a matrix dependency language.

The difference is subtle: Programming languages are much more flexible, but you have to tell it each and every step to take. A matrix dependency language figures out the order of execution.

It can be a subtle, but important difference. In standard Ant, basic control structures like while loops, for loops, and if/then statements are missing.

It sounds like what you want to do would be much easier with a standard computer language. Maybe Python, Perl, or even a shell script.

Type "ant -help" on the command line, and you'll see there's no real way to pass parameters into Ant like you can with regular programming languages. Instead, you can set *properties* on the command line that Ant can then use:

```
$ant -Ddeploy.classfile=src/classes/myClass.class deploy
```

The -D allows you to set a property when calling the *deploy* task. You can then use the *deploy.classfile* property to use it in an Ant  task in your  target. I would make a rough estimate that even such a simple *build.xml* file would require about 20 to thirty lines. This is especially true that you will be giving it a class file or a directory, and you'll have to handle them differently which would require a second target. Not only that, but it would be hard to understand the workflow.

Here's an idea, why not use the `destdir` target in your `<javac>` task to create the required `*.class` files in the `deploy` directory in the first place. One of the prime practices with Ant is to separate out files you build from files that are in your repository. It makes cleaning up much, much easier. Plus, the `<javac>` task knows not to rebuild classfiles for source files that haven't changed.

```
<target name="compile"
    description="Compile your source files">

    <property name="main.destdir" value="${basedir}/deploy/classes"/>
    <property name="main.srcdir" value="${basedir}/src"/>

    <path id="main.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/>
    </path>

    <javac srcdir="${main.srcdir}"
        destdir="${main.destdir}"
        classpathref="main.classpath"/>
</target>
```

Now, you don't have to copy files from your source directory to your deploy directory. Even better, `<javac>` doesn't recompile source files that haven't changed. Let Ant do the job it was designed for, and for everything else, use a good scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a problem with changing your input command line string, here's something that should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="Deploy" default="copy">

    <!--
        This script is called in the following manner:

        ant deploy -Dsource.dir=src/classes     (to copy the entire directory)
        ant deploy -Dsource.dir=src/classes -Dsource.module=myClass.class
                                                (to copy one class)

    -->

    <!-- <property name="source.dir" value="src/com/ggl/unzip" />  -->
    <!-- <property name="source.module" value="myClass.class" />  -->

    <target name="copy">
        <condition property="source.module.text" value="all files">
            <not>
                <isset property="source.module" />
            </not>
        </condition>

        <condition property="source.module" value="**.*">
            <not>
                <isset property="source.module" />
            </not>
        </condition>

        <property name="source.module.text" value="${source.module}" />

        <echo>Copying ${source.module.text} from ${source.dir} to deploy/${source.dir}</echo>

        <copy todir="deploy/${source.dir}" overwrite="true" verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="${source.dir}">
                <include name="${source.module}" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the good old fashioned `cp` in a shell script rather than an ant script? `cp -r` would allow you to copy directories recursively...

Answer (score 0):

To provide values to ant from console you need to use ant-properties, you can pass them with `-D` prefix, so you must call your build as:
    ant -Ddst=deploy -Dsrc=src/classes/
(also I suggest to switch src and dst positions - as in `cp` command)
In build.xml you can access this properties as `${dst}` and `${src}`.

I it is not suits you, then you need make new ant entry point class for ant and call

```
ant -main <YourClass> arg2 arg3
```

Example is [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)(first example)